# Assigning value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am fetching the user input data from textarea on button click. If a user put some hyperlink code inside textarea, the function automatically recognize and add `rel=nofollow`. Now I need to assign these new hyperlink code inside textarea again and replace the old one.

I am able to add `rel=nofollow` and able to alert it

```js
function naming() {
  var rel_attribute = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
  var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rel_attribute, 'text/html');
  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach((a) => {
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    alert(a.outerHTML);
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Execute Function</a>
```

Comment: to clarify, are you just looking to update the textfield value?
i.e user enters html in to the textarea, the function updates the text they entered to have the nofollow?

Comment: No clue what your problem actually is.

Comment: What you want to do with the text from the textarea?

Comment: I only need to update the value of textarea with rel attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) interface to convert your `DOMParser` instance into HTML string, then affect your `<textarea>`'s value property with the HTML string.

You'll need to do some other processes if you want to only have the `<body>` tags' content.

```js
function naming() {
  const eArea = document.getElementById('textareaCode'),
    dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(eArea.value, 'text/html');
  
  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach(a => a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow'));
  
  // That's here!
  eArea.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(dom);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>

<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Execute Function</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
function naming() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareaCode');
  var rel_attribute = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
  var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rel_attribute, 'text/html');
  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach((a) => {
    let original = a.outerHTML
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(original, a.outerHTML)
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode" cols=70 rows=5>
<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Execute Function</a>
</textarea>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Execute Function</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out as follows,

```js
let counter = 1;

function naming() {
  var rel_attribute = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;

  var anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rel_attribute, 'text/html');
  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach((a) => {
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    
    a.onclick = naming;
    a.innerText = "Manish " + counter++;
    
    for(let i=0; i < anchorTags.length; i++){
      anchorTags[i].remove();
    }
    
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    console.log(anchorTags);
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Execute Function</a>
```